# Why is my swap not being activated automatically via fstab?

Tags: linux, embedded, fstab, swap

I've got a Linux embedded system that I'm experimenting with (the Elektor Embedded Linux Made Easy board, based on the GNUBLIN http://en.gnublin.org/index.php/GNUBLIN-Elektor). I'm using the 3.3 kernel provided by them (http://en.gnublin.org/index.php/Kernel_compile_%2B_Module_installation), which I've configured and compiled myself. I built the root file system myself using buildroot.

I've been experimenting with swap on this board (it's only got 8MB RAM!) and I've got it working. However I can't seem to get the system to automatically mount and activate the swap via fstab. My swap is implemented as a dedicated partition on the microSD card (mmcblk0p4). Here is my fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount pt>     <type>   <options>         <dump> <pass>
/dev/root       /              ext4     rw,noauto         0      1
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /media/mmc_1   ext2     defaults          0      0
/dev/mmcblk0p4  none           swap     auto              0      0
proc            /proc          proc     defaults          0      0
devpts          /dev/pts       devpts   defaults,gid=5,mode=620   0      0
tmpfs           /dev/shm       tmpfs    mode=0777         0      0
tmpfs           /tmp           tmpfs    mode=1777         0      0
sysfs           /sys           sysfs    defaults          0      0
```

swap works, because if I enter `swapon -a` in the command line, it becomes activated, as reported by `free`. But it just won't activate automatically on boot.

My other entries in fstab work fine - for example, /dev/mmcblk0p1 is auto mounted correctly on boot.

I've pasted the output of the boot process here: http://pastebin.com/0qQ4RAd8

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where does your buildroots init system run `swapon`?

Comment: @mtm I don't know. When I built the buildroot system I didn't notice any settings regarding swap. I assumed that if support was built into the kernel, whatever program parses the fstab file would be responsible for turning on swap if a relevant entry existed.

Comment: I was just thinking it might not be default in an embedded environment? A `grep -r swap` might point you towards what is doing the work or other configuration. Sorry haven't used buildroot but if you figure out the 'what', the 'why' usually follows.

Comment: It's up to the init scripts. Init scripts for desktop/server systems look up swap entries from `fstab` and bring them up fairly early in the boot process, but many embedded distributions don't, because swap on embedded systems is rare.

Answer (score 4):

Exchange `auto` with `sw` in the fstab line. This tells the system to activate it using swapon after booting.